# Tricky Python 3.5 CSV Puzzle - efficiently create 100 lists from a CSV file without referencing criteria each time

Tags: python, csv

My project was to take 100 different colors and collect people's one-word reactions to them. So there are two columns: Color and Reaction. There are about 600 cases. **My goal is to take every reaction for the same color and merge them into some sort of list.**

So, I'd need to take all reactions to a specific color and merge them into a list and call that variable [Color]_All_Reactions.

**If there were just (say) three colors, I could just iterate through every reaction associated with a specified color to add those colors to a list. But I have too many colors to do that for.** I need to write something to iterate through all reactions, create an All_Reactions list for each unique color, and then append the content associated with each unique color to that color's All_Reactions list.

[Here is a simple file with just 3 colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTBH8.png). I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a dictionary.**

Create a dictionary with `color` as key and list of reactions as `value`. This way, iterating over it will be a breeze.

**Pro tip -**

Use `collections.defaultdict` instead of a regular `dict`.

Comment: The reactions object, instead of a list, could be a `defaultdict(int)`. So he could count the occurrences of every reaction.

Comment: @Roberto That is a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with something like this

```
color_reactions = dict()
with open('color_reactions.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        color, reaction = line.strip().split(',')
        color_reactions.setdefault(color, []).append(reaction)
```